# Making a Program for Grouping in java - Bigdecimal

Tags: java, grouping, bigdecimal

I am making a program for some of my teachers that takes a list of students from a .txt file and puts them into random groups with any size that the teacher inputs. When there are a number of students that cannot be evenly divided into that number, I want it to take the remainder and make a special group with the extra students. this is what I have. Note: I have never used bigdecimal and I need some help with the remainder function.

```
    public static void results(String [] names) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int groups = 0;
        do{
            System.out.println("How many groups do you want?");
            if(scan.hasNextInt()) groups = scan.nextInt();
            else scan.next();
        } while(groups == 0);
        BigDecimal numbergroups = new BigDecimal("1.5");
        int numberlastgroup = BigDecimal.remainder(BigDecimal.);
}
```

String[] Names is the list of names.

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is the question/problem you're facing?

Comment: Why are you using BigDecimal? Natural groups haven't fractions.

Answer (score 0):

If your question points to the the usage of BigDecimal - it gets used like this:

```
// remainder = dividend % divisor
BigDecimal dividend = new BigDecimal("100");
BigDecimal divisor = new BigDecimal("3");
BigDecimal remainder = dividend.remainder(divisor);

// convert BigDecimal to int
int remainderAsInt = remainder.intValue();
```

See also the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divideToIntegralValue%28java.math.BigDecimal%29)